# How can I reliably get ComboBox.Text value in Visual Basic .Net while debugging?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, delegates

AFAIK this should be a very simple task, but after 2 different attempts I'm still unable to verify the current value of a ComboBox in Visual Basic .Net 4.5.

How can I get it reliably? My previous 2 attempts in detail below so that you can hopefully show me where my error is.

**Attempt 1(a):**

Attempt accessing the `MyComboBox.Text` property from the Watch window while debugging in Visual Studio Express 2013. Instead of retrieving the text property, I get this message in the Watch Window:

`An exception 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException' occurred`.

This seems to be "normal" behaviour and workarounds are described at a helpful article on microsoft.com [1].

**Attempt 1(b):**

Adding the line `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` as described at [1] did not help. I included this line in the `New()` Sub of my form code and verified that `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` was indeed set to `False` at run time by adding it as an expression to the watch window. There was no change in behaviour and I received the same error message as listed in **Attempt 1** above.

**Attempt 2:**

By following that first article [1] I added the following code to my form module:

```
Delegate Function GetBoardTextCallback() As String
Private Function GetBoardText() As String
    If Me.BoardBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New GetBoardTextCallback(AddressOf GetBoardText)
        Return Me.Invoke(d)
    Else
        Return Me.BoardBox.Text
    End If
End Function
```

Now in my Watch Window when I add `GetBoardText()` there is a delay of about 5 seconds and then a message appears in the Value column about Unable to Evaluate Expression, then after I hit refresh on the expression I get this message: `Cannot evaluate expression because we are stopped in a place where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code of the current method may be optimized.`

I am new to delegates so I suspect my implementation has something wrong with it. I must admit I'm a little baffled as to why simply reading the value of a form element needs to be so complicated (even though the concept of separate threads for visual elements seems straight forward). How Can I reliably get (let alone set!) the `Text` property of a ComboBox in Visual Basic .Net in a way that works while debugging in my Watch Window, as well as (hopefully) also working as an expression I can use anywhere in my code?! Am I going to have to create a new and unique delegate function for each and every get/set/element member combination for all my form elements? Please no!

**EDIT (Attempt 2 code verified as threadsafe):**
On further investigation I've verified many times that my code sample in Attempt 2 really does work, but there must be some crucial error in my understanding of the VS 2013 debugger. If the reason that Watch Window expressions were failing was because of cross-threading problems, then they *should* work if calling my thread-safe getters (after all, those getters work just fine for other threads at run-time that didn't create the form controls). So what is so unique about the debugger's thread(s) that they can't use those thread-safe functions that I wrote?! Addressing that problem is really the answer to this question.

**EDIT (bugs in debugger tools?):**
Also, according to other MS documentation [2] there are tools in the debugger for debugging multi-threaded applications. *However* adding watch expressions `Me.BoardBox.Text` and `GetBoardText()` for *all* available threads all produce the same result. This is more evidence IMO that there is something weird/unique about the debuggers access to thread memory or it's process. If it were just a "debugger is looking at the wrong thread" type problem, then the multi-threading debugging options should have fixed it.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx
[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164739.aspx

Comment: What is the combobox type? Dropdown list, combo, or editable list?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman DropDownStyle = DropDownList in the properties pane. I couldn't see any other properties in there that distinguished the options you're talking about. It's a box with a down-pointing black arrow on the right, you click anywhere on the box and a list drops down from which you must select 1 item. After you select that 1 item the list goes back "up" and the selected item is shown as text on the combo box. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman The object type is definitely `ComboBox` and not `Listbox` if that's what you mean.

Comment: I have had issues using ComboBox.Text in the past. I have found that using ComboBox.SelectedItem.Text works better. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Do you mean `BoardBox.SelectedText`?

Comment: No, that will be text that has been highlighted when the ComboBox's DropDownStyle is set to either Simple or DropDown.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman `BoardBox.SelectedItem.Text` produces an identical results to my Attempt 1(a)

Answer (score 2):

When you are debugging across threads, you will not be able to get the value of something on another thread.  The Invoke method shown in your question will allow your code to get the value from the ComboBox, but doesn't apply when you are debugging.

From [Debug Multithreaded Applications in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx)

> > Debugging a multithreaded application that has a user interface can be especially difficult. In that case, you might consider running the application on a second computer and using remote debugging. For information, see [Remote Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).

Comment: I suppose using a completely separate computer would be a way to achieve what I'm looking for, but I find it hard to believe that all VB .Net programmers who need to inspect properties of form elements have no option other than to use 2 computers every time they program.

Comment: You are entering the world of multithreaded applications. This is a Visual Studio issue. It is not specific to any of the .NET languages. If your application was single threaded, you wouldn't be running into this issue.

Comment: Cool thankyou - I had a fault assumption that VB always used a separate thread for "owning" or updating visual elements, but sounds like this problem is unique to scenarios where I create custom threads and it normally doesn't come up in other cases.

Comment: The concept of a single thread owning the UI actually comes from Windows it's self.  This is true no matter what language you are using, VB, C#, C++.  You can only touch UI from the thread that created the UI element.  While you can create UI from different threads it will just bring you a world of hurt;  keep things simple and only create or access the UI from a single thread.

Comment: @BradleyUffner so it's an accepted design paradigm in .Net programming that worker threads can never read properties of WinForm Controls? Surely it's common enough, as in my case, to have spawned worker threads that need to access control members periodically as they are executed in case control properties were updated after the thread stated. It's not so much access from other threads that's the problem, it's access form the debugger tools.

Comment: That's correct.  Windows (not .NET specifically) does not allow access to controls from threads that do not own the control.  Any access from a different thread must be marshaled to the gui thread.